# Is there any timeout setting on an EJB components?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

Is there any timeout setting on an EJB component?

In this EJB component, there is a code running sql for more than 30 minutes. 
Hence, timeout is trigger, every sql statements are rolled back.

I have set JPA timeout to 1 hour but seems there is another additional setting in EJB.

Tqs.
Jimmy

Comment: How did you set the JPA timeout? In Jboss you can set it in [its specific way](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout).

Comment: Which application server did you use?

Comment: Im using weblogic, I have set JPA timeout to one hour in weblogic. However, the error was thrown from EJB component.

Comment: @TransactionTimeoutSeconds(value = 60) may help. However I dunno which jar that is able to import weblogic.javaee.TransactionTimeOutSeconds.

Comment: As I wrote in the last part of the answer, the transaction timeout won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since EJB 3.1 this is achievable with @Asyncrhonous ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html )

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<ResultObject> longRunningMethod () {

}
```

Then you can call it with

```
Future<ResultObject> result = ejb.longRunningMethod();
result.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Note that the default transaction mode for the longRunningMethod will be REQUIRED_NEW. This can make things tricky.

Apart from this, all the containers provide a way to set transaction timeout. But this doesn't work as expected. The method doesn't return, it is just marked failed after the timeout duration and throws transaction timeout exception after the method completes and not immediately after the timeout is exceeded.

In general, if your database transaction runs longer than 30 min. and ejb method is not the way to go. This seems like a batch process.

Comment: Really no way? Maybe putting in annotation or xml somewhere.

Comment: But ur solution seems cannot increase the timeout setting.

Comment: Why ? You can take the timeout (15 seconds in the code) from configuration or any other source. What do you mean by increase exactly ?